# Using MS EXCEL Query to pull data from Sequel Server. Date fields not compatible

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel-2010

Attempting to write MS Excel query to pull from Sequel Server. Wanted to use
DATEFIELD > ((Now()-365) AND Now())

Host of syntax errors so I tried the normal Excel date parm for today(). Or DATE(), and SQL CURDATE(). None of which has worked.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What errors did you get?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't done that in a long while, but you could try the SQL function `GETDATE()`:

```
DATEFIELD between DATEADD(yy,-1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider selecting it as your accepted answer.  Thanks!